# The stress of the prefix 'inter-'

Tags: pronunciation, stress

In some words, the stress is on the first syllable of *inter*, for stance, *intercourse*, *interview*, *internet*, *interval*.

However, there are also some words, in which the stress is on the second syllable of *inter*, for instance, *interpret*, *internal*.

What's the cause of this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Internet* is a compound formed according to English compound rules from *inter-* and *net(work).* When compounds are formed in English, each part retains its stress and the stronger stress goes on the first part. So *internet* is pronounced with the same stress pattern as a compound noun like "underwear".

Although *intercourse* and *interview* did not originate as English compounds, I think it's plausible that they have become interpreted as such, based on the fact that *course* and *view* do exist in English as independent words.

In contrast, *interval, interpret, internal* end in *-val,* *-pret* and *-nal* which have no existence as independent words.

Why is there a difference in stress between those three? I'm not sure.

- *Internal* follows a common pattern for adjectives ending in *-al*: they are stressed on the second-to-last syllable if there are two or more consonant letters between the *al* and the preceding vowel letter. I discuss this rule further in an answer I wrote to the question "["Substantival" - doesn't fit the normal stress paradigm](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68863)" posted by mbm29414 on ELL.
- *Interpret* is a verb, and its pronunciation might be related to a principle that Greg Lee notes in his [answer to the question *Why do nouns and verbs which are stressed differently all exhibit the same variation?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/315887/77227):

  > Nouns and adjectives tolerate more unstressed syllables than verbs do.

  However, *interview* is also used as a verb and has the same stress in that case as when it is used as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of *internal*, it's because it uses the Latin prefix *in-* as opposed to *ex-* (out of). The other words are based on *inter-* meaning between.

This doesn't explain *interpret*, though, since that also carries the sense 'between [two people]'.